HotChocolate can't resolve Single type on DAB schema definition
I am working on a project using GraphQL, HotChocolate, and the newly release Data API Builder (DAB).
I am using HotChocolate's schema stitching in an attempt to use DAB within the remote schema function.
However, DAB's schema definition built from my MSSQL database within Azure contains a Single which is giving me the error:
"1. Cannot Resolve type 'Single' (HotChocolate.Types)"
As the error suggests, and from my reading, HotChocolate.Types does not contain a definition for Single.
Here is part of my schema definition:

input DefaultValue {
  Byte: Byte
  Short: Short
  Int: Int
  Long: Long
  String: String 
  Boolean: Boolean
  Single: Single <---------
  Float: Float
  Decimal: Decimal
  DateTime: DateTime
  ByteArray: ByteArray
  LocalTime: LocalTime
}


I have tried adding the C# Single type using the AddType service.
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddType<Single>() //Adding single type here
    .AddRemoteSchema("DABConnection");

I have also tried defining my own single type with derives from the float type but the same error persists.

Can you open an issue here ? https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/issues
